# Jquery Cycle() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, slideshow

I'm studying Jquery, and I was trying to do a simple SlideShow, but nothing happens...

Here's my HTML

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SlideShow</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="slides">       
        <img src="imgs/1.jpg">
        <img src="imgs/2.jpg">
        <img src="imgs/3.jpg">
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#slides").cycle({

                fx: 'fade',
                speed:2000,
                timeout:4000,
            });
        })
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Cycle.js"></script>  


</body>
</html>
```

My Css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#slides{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I also tried to change, this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

for this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
```

Nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include jQuery before your `Cycle` plugin, so reverse the order of your scripts here:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Cycle.js"></script>
```

Also, it's better to include `CSS` before `Javascript` as well as putting your `Javascript` at the bottom of your page before closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Hi @Felix !
I used to write my scripts in the bottom of my body, and the css on the <header>. Is that right ?

Comment: Hey @Felix. Updated my HTML, still the same ;\

Comment: Please make sure the path to your script is correct. Btw, did you receive any error in the console?

Comment: The path is correct. And I got this in the console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

UPDATE:

I just putted the <script> code AFTER the jquery reference call, and It's working now...

Thanks a bunch @Felix !! o/

Comment: The error stated that you've not included jQuery properly or your custom jQuery code running before you've included jQuery. It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/qR63P/